# Android Two listviews and adapters

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have below layout file with:
2 listviews,
2 textview,
2 mapfragments,
when i try to load my String[] to first listView using adatper i have strange error. Any suggestions whats wrong? I'm sure that this problem is because of listview and adapter. When i remove it and start activity without adapter, layout is loading ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LLglowny"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="1"
              tools:context="com.example.norbert.routespreparation2.DistanceAdvisor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLtrasa1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvInfoTrasa1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/LvTrasa1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">


        </ListView>


        <fragment android:id="@+id/map1"
                  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="0.5">


        </fragment>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLtrasa2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TvInfoTrasa2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="TEST"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/LvTrasa2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
        </ListView>

        <fragment

            android:id="@+id/map2"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">


        </fragment>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and class code:

```
public class DistanceAdvisor extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @BindView(R.id.LvTrasa1)
    ListView LvTrasa1;
    @BindView(R.id.LvTrasa2)
    ListView LvTrasa2;
    @BindView(R.id.LLtrasa1)
    LinearLayout LLtrasy;
    @BindView(R.id.LLglowny)
    LinearLayout LLglowny;
    @BindView(R.id.TvInfoTrasa1)
    TextView TvInfoTrasa1;
    @BindView(R.id.TvInfoTrasa2)
    TextView TvInfoTrasa2;

    private GoogleMap map1, map2;
    private int ItemClickedPosition;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private Cursor data;
    private String[] tablicaAdresow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_distance_advisor);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment2 = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);

        supportMapFragment1.getMapAsync(this);
        supportMapFragment2.getMapAsync(this);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        ItemClickedPosition = b.getInt("ItemClicked", 0);


        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        data = databaseHelper.getData();
        tablicaAdresow = new String[100000];

        StworzTabliceAdresow();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_distance_advisor, R.id.LvTrasa1, tablicaAdresow);
        LvTrasa1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void StworzTabliceAdresow() {
        String stringAdresow;
        data.moveToPosition(ItemClickedPosition);
        stringAdresow = data.getString(4);

        tablicaAdresow = stringAdresow.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
        Log.d("pokaz", String.valueOf(tablicaAdresow.length));

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map1 = googleMap;
        map2 = googleMap;
    }
}
```

and error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.norbert.routespreparation2, PID: 7764
                                                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #34: Duplicate id 0x
```

Comment: I think the problem is in `StworzTabliceAdresow()` method. Can you post the log printed there?

Comment: 04-22 15:09:40.126 3383-3383/com.example.norbert.routespreparation2 D/pokaz: 6                            it correctly retrieve data which i want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stupid but i forget to create single row layout with TextView.
For example if a make single row layout with id sLineLayout which will be include TextView with id row, ArrayAdapter initializing should look like this:
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.sLineLayout, R.id.row, tab);

it's quite easy, maybe it help somebody:)